# Python - ImportError: No module named psutil

Tags: python

I am writing a python script for an eBPF program and getting the error in the subject. I have done `sudo python -m pip install psutil` as recommended in other questions. I am getting the following message:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (5.9.0)
```

Python 2 is required for the program I am writing unfortunately. The code for the program looks as below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from bcc import BPF
from bcc.utils import printb
import tkMessageBox as messagebox
import psutil
...
def action_process(pid, action):
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    if(action == "suspend"):
        p.suspend()
    elif (action == "kill"):
        p.kill()
    elif (action == "resume"):
        p.resume()
...
```

Comment: What error are you seeing exactly? The deprecation warning is just a warning but perhaps you need to set up `pyenv` or similar as a local install?

Comment: @KenY-N ImportError: No module named psutil is the error I am seeing

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `pip install --no-binary :all: psutil`.

Thats how it is described in the documentation.
https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst